# как сделать генератор автомобильного номера?

Tags: java

нужно сделать генератор автомобильных номеров в таком формате:

```
XYZ - различные буквы, N - цифры, R - регион (от 01 до 199)

XNNNYZR - пример, A111BC197, Y777HC66
```

получилось только вот так:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] chars = new String[]{"А", "В","Е", "К", "М", "Н", "О", "Р", "С", "Т", "У", "Х", };
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
                String currChar = chars[i];
                String number = String.format("%s(%d%d%d)(%s%s)(%d%d%d)", currChar, j, j, j, currChar, currChar, j, j,j);
                System.out.println(number);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

выдает следующее:

```
А(111)(АА)(111)
А(222)(АА)(222)
А(333)(АА)(333)
А(444)(АА)(444)
А(555)(АА)(555)
А(666)(АА)(666)
А(777)(АА)(777)
А(888)(АА)(888)
А(999)(АА)(999)
В(111)(ВВ)(111)
В(222)(ВВ)(222)
В(333)(ВВ)(333)
В(444)(ВВ)(444)
В(555)(ВВ)(555)
В(666)(ВВ)(666)
В(777)(ВВ)(777)
В(888)(ВВ)(888)
etc
```

пожалуйста, помогите кто чем может)

Comment: Задачки с skillbox надо решать самому

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прям все комбинации перебрать надо? Можно вот так, например:

```
IntStream.range(1, 200).forEach(
        region -> Arrays.stream(chars).forEach(
                letterA -> Arrays.stream(chars).forEach(
                        letterB -> Arrays.stream(chars).forEach(
                                letterC -> IntStream.range(1, 1000).forEach(
                                        num -> System.out.println(String.format("%s %03d %s%s %03d", letterA, num, letterB, letterC, region))
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
);
```

Comment: здорово! спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Я попробовал решить так. Проверил, совпадений в этом "листе" нет.

```
        ArrayList<String> coolNumbersList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> coolNumbersListWithoutRegion = new ArrayList<>();

        String numberplate = "";
        String numberplateWithoutRegion = "";

        char x; // первая буква
        char z; // вторая буква
        char y; // третья буква

        ArrayList<Character> allowedLetters = new ArrayList<>(){{
            add('А');
            add('В');
            add('Е');
            add('К');
            add('М');
            add('Н');
            add('О');
            add('Р');
            add('С');
            add('Т');
            add('У');
            add('Х');
        }};

        for(Character firstLetter : allowedLetters){
            x = firstLetter;
            for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++){
                for (Character secondLetter : allowedLetters){
                    z = secondLetter;
                    for(Character thirdLetter : allowedLetters){
                        y = thirdLetter;
                        numberplateWithoutRegion = String.format("%c%d%d%d%c%c", x, n, n, n, z, y);
                        coolNumbersListWithoutRegion.add(numberplateWithoutRegion);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (String numberWithoutRegion : coolNumbersListWithoutRegion) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 199; j++){
                if(j < 10){
                    numberplate = String.format("%s0%d", numberWithoutRegion, j);
                    coolNumbersList.add(numberplate);
                }
                else {
                    numberplate = String.format("%s%d", numberWithoutRegion, j);
                    coolNumbersList.add(numberplate);
                }
            }
        }

        return coolNumbersList;
    }
```